# show panel link_to in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to provide edit and view links in active admin user's show panel which has data from abc model. When I click the view link it search the current user id in "abc" model. I want it to search for abc model id's which are related to particular user.
relation: abc has_many users.

How to provide the path??
Any help would be appreciable

```
show do
    attributes_table do
        rows :id, :name, :email
    end 
    panel "abc" do
        table_for (user.abc) do |a|
            column :model
            column :registration_number
            column do link_to "View", admin_abc_path end
            column do link_to "Edit", edit_admin_abc_path end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create object for the column and fetch id using the object.
Try this.

```
column do |p| link_to "View", "admin/abc/#{p.id}" end
```

Comment: Thanks..I did similar thing which worked for me column do |p| link_to "View", admin_abc_path(p.id) end